# Question - Maximum range of Ballistic gunshot formula: $V_M=\sqrt{Rg}$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I have a question on physics, broke my head, saw the answer, then I see there is a formula for  calculating the distance from the end of the mouth of the rocket to the finish line.
If the length of the mouth of the rocket is $9\text{m}$ and the length of the gunshot is $20000\text{m}$, then the formula is:
$V_M=\sqrt{Rg}$,
when $V_M=$ Velocity from end of mouth.
$R$= The length of the distance.
$g=$its pretty much immediately known, the gravitational acceleration

My question is, how do I get to this formula? I had a hard time with this question, just to realize such a thing exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be covered in most first mechanics courses, the parabola for a given initial $(v_x,v_y)$ is
$$
y=-\frac{g}{2v_x^2} x^2 + \frac{v_y}{v_x} x
$$
with zeroes at $x=0$ and $x=\frac{2 v_x v_y}{g}$.

With some trigonometry, $v_x = v\cos\theta$ and $v_y=v\sin\theta$ and $2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin(2\theta)$ which attains a maximum of 1 at a 45° angle, at which angle the nontrivial root is $x=v^2/g.$

To actually get to that first equation requires understanding the basics of ballistic motion, that probably requires actually doing a physics course. But all the rest of the stuff is just kind of algebra and trig, just solve a lot of problems and you will get there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
Actually, yes I am on a physics course (academics). but I don't remember this. we learnt this 3 months ago (now I am practicing to a final test, so I went back in the materials... )
About the parabola for a given initial, that I can 100% say I never saw it :(
I didn't understand about how you got to that $X=0$ and the other $X$,
About the trigonometry, that I understood, but the other stuff I can't really know what you did. Do you have any link with an explanation to it? I searched google and couldn't find. I will try search ballistic motion now, thanks.

Comment: Oh Thanks, I just found a way to study it more, I searched the ballistic motion and suddenly I got many sites which explain this more thoroughly, thanks alot!!